# Create database from backup file using C# on the remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, restore

I've got a backup of my database.

After editing it in my program, it's a new `newDb.bak` file(on my PC).

How could I restore this new database on the remote SQL Server, if I have the connection string (I know ip, login and password)?

Mainly I have to do this only using C# (not the SQL Server Management Studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no any direct way** to restore database remotely from local backup file.

But the alternative solution is making a shared location in some where (local side or server side it's not matter) which both of the client and server have access to there.
(**Update:**  Also, make sure the SQL server that will be performing the restore has permissions to the directory that you're copying the backup to. – @KSib)
Then restore the database from file :

1. Copy `newDb.bak` to `\\serverip\$sharedfolder\newDb.bak` on the
   server.
2. `RESTORE DATABASE YOURDB FROM DISK = N'\\serverip\$sharedfolder\newDb.bak';`

if you want i can share the source code of restoring database in `C#`.

**Update**: Another solution is that create a table which contains `varbinary` column, Insert the backup file content from local to it by `SqlCommand` or `SqlBulkCopy` to and then export the file content to some where in your server by `bcp` such this:

`BCP "SELECT FileContent FROM createdTable WHERE ID = 1000" queryout "C:\newDB.bak" -T`

Then you can execute the restore command easily!

Also you can create a server side `StoredProcedure` containing a transaction to get the file content as input parameter and do all the command as one transaction.

I hope to be helpful for you :).

Comment: > there is no any direct way
Oooh crap.

Comment: Also, make sure the SQL server that will be performing the restore has permissions to the directory that you're copying the backup to.

Comment: @KamikyIT I found a new way and update my post. Let me know if is not clear :)

Comment: @KSib I updated my answer and I put your recommendation in it. Regards.